# lwIP combine several tcp/http segments to single packet

Tags: lwip

Having trouble with lwIP combining 2 separate `tcp_write()` segments to 1 packet when sending (`tcp_output()`). Is there a way to make lwip stop combining the segments and send each segment separate (as 2 packets as it should)? been searching with no luck

lwip version 1.3.0 used

Comment: Is there a specific problem that arises from having them combined? To the application layer it should not matter if they are combined or not.

Comment: yeah, we have a web server which receives http request sent from the lwip unit. The server only recognize a single packet with correct data format and discards any other informations. In other words, the server dont recognize combined packets and discard them as invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of dividing webpages on chunk and send it. after creating a chunk and write it to buffer using tcp_write, I use tcp_output to force the push the data to client but I fount out no matter what, the data will be send to client only after the received callback ends.